# two dimensional array in java - difficulties

Tags: java

I'm used to python and django but I've recently started learning java. Since I don't have much time because of work I missed a lot of classes and I'm a bit confused now that I have to do a work.

**EDIT**
The program is suppose to attribute points according to the time each athlete made in bike and race. I have 4 extra tables for male and female with points and times.
I have to compare then and find the corresponding points for each time (linear interpolation).

So this was my idea to read the file, and use an arrayList

One of the things I'm having difficulties is creating a two dimensional array.
I have a file similar to this one:

```
12    M    23:56    62:50
36    F    59:30    20:60
```

Where the first number is an athlete, the second the gender and next time of different races (which needs to be converted into seconds).

Since I can't make an array mixed (int and char), I have to convert the gender to 0 and 1.

so where is what I've done so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner fileTime = new Scanner (new FileReader ("time.txt"));
        while (fileTime.hasNext()) {
            String value = fileTime.next();
            // Modify gender by o and 1, this way I'm able to convert string into integer
            if (value.equals("F"))
                value = "0";
            else if (value.equals("M"))
                value = "1";
            // Verify which values has :
            int index = valor.indexOf(":");
            if (index != -1) {
                String [] temp = value.split(":");
                for (int i=0; i<temp.length; i++) {
                    // convert string to int
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
                    // I wanted to multiply the first number by 60 to convert into seconds and add the second number to the first
                   num * 60; // but this way I multiplying everything
            }
        }
        }
```

I'm aware that there's probably easier ways to do this but honestly I'm a bit confused, any lights are welcome.

Comment: What exactly is your program supposed to do? Are you just outputting the same file with the times converted to seconds?

Comment: For `M` and `F`, you could define an enum

Comment: I've updated my question, sorry @Taymon I should have explained.

Comment: @fge using an enum how can I put all these values into the same array?

Comment: That's not the question. The question is to have the gender defined as discrete value: `public enum Gender { M, N }` -- and then use `Gender.valueOf(thestring)`

Comment: but I have to keep the data received from the file into something, array.. because each line is an athlete. with enum how can I keep the gender associated with the values?

Comment: Make your `Athlete` class have a `Gender` member

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because an array works well to store the data in one language does not mean it is the best way to store the data in another language.

Instead of trying to make a two dimensional array, you can make a single array (or [collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html)) of a custom class.

```
public class Athlete {
  private int _id;
  private boolean _isMale;
  private int[] _times;
  //...
}
```

How you intend to use the data may change the way you structure the class. But this is a simple direct representation of the data line you described.

Comment: what I want to do is for each athlete, male or female, comparing the time they made in bike and race with another table and attribute points. Wouldn't an arrayList be appropriate in this case? that was my idea..

Comment: @pavid: If the set of times is fixed to just just those two, it might be best to just make them separate variables. You would then have a list of `Athelete`s that you can iterate over as needed.

Comment: @pavid: The main point is that the serialized format of the data might not be the best representation of that same data in code. If you are only concerned with the number of points each athlete gets, you would use a map to pair the athlete id with the point total.

Comment: yes, the purpose it the number of points, but to find those points, I need to know the times, to find the corresponding points through linear interpolation. I saw lots of person using map, in the internet, but I haven't learned that so I though about arrayList

Answer (score 1):

Python is a dynamically-typed language, which means you can think of each row as a tuple, or even as a list/array if you like. The Java idiom is to be stricter in typing. So, rather than having a list of list of elements, your Java program should define a class that represents a the information in each line, and then instantiate and populate objects of that class. In other words, if you want to program in idiomatic Java, this is not a two-dimensional array problem; it's a `List<MyClass>` problem.

Comment: @pavid No, the idea is that the Java approach isn't to have a list of lists, it's to have a list of MyClass objects, where MyClass has fields for the athlete's number, gender, and probably a List<Long> of times of each race.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file line by line:

```
while (fileTime.hasNext())
```

Instead of `hasNext` use `hasNextLine`.

Read the next line instead of next token:

```
String value = fileTime.next();
// can be
String line = fileTime.nextLine();
```

Split the line into four parts with something as follows:

```
String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
```

Access the parts using `parts[0]`, `parts[1]`, `parts[2]` and `parts[3]`. And you already know what's in what. Easily process them.

Comment: it's actually a nice idea.. but would it be better to use an arrayList to store the information?

Comment: Yes sure. Just like unholysampler suggested come up with a class and use something like: `List<Athlete> athletes = new ArrayList<Athlete>();`